# Executing a query from inside Java to create a function

Tags: java, mysql

The following code runs find inside a MySQL client, or piped to mysql. When I attempt to run it as a query inside Java 
I get an error

> Error executing SQL statement
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter @'

This is the first query I've had issues with. I've tried replacing linefeeds with spaces to run it as one line statement, worked everywhere but Java. Tried without the DROP statement, same problem.

> Error Code 1064 (Parse Error), State 42000

Thanks for any help you can offer.

---

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS escape_query_result;

delimiter @

CREATE FUNCTION escape_query_result(label CHAR(255))
    RETURNS CHAR(255)
BEGIN
    RETURN (REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(label, "\\", "\\\\"), "|", "\\|"), "=", "\\="));
END@

delimiter ;
```

Since I can't post an answer, editing my question:

Found my answer.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25019

You can not change the delimiter from a query. Executing without the delimiter calls worked.

Comment: If you're treating it as a query rather than an update, that could be your issue. Also take a look at prepared statements http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.sql/InsertPs.html

Comment: You actually can post an answer for your own question. (Is it stopping you from doing that?)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in your MySQL connection string, you need to set allowMultiQueries to true; otherwise, it is an error to send a query to MySQL that combines multiple statements with a semicolon. See the documentation here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

The default setting for allowMultiQueries is false.

However, setting this to false can actually be useful for security reasons because most SQL injection attacks work by injecting a semicolon into your query; if allowMultiQueries is false then these injections will result in errors instead of, say, deleting all rows in one of your tables. In this situation it may be better to just send the DROP as a separate query.

I'm not sure how this interacts with the DELIMITER command in MySQL, however. Maybe someone else can help you with that, as I don't have time to test it out right now.

Comment: i can run multiple like "insert into table (...) VALUES (...); insert into table (...) VALUES (...);" but I can't get it to create a stored procedure or function.